# Arrays with printwriter and displaying them

Tags: java, arrays, printwriter

What im trying to do is make this txt file into an array, then with the numbers that are incorrect(not numbers) put them into the pw wrong.txt and display them

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class MorenoJonathonTranslator
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
  Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt"));
    ArrayList<String> alphabeticPhoneNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
    int i = 0;

System.out.println("Original: ");


System.out.println("Numberical: ");
    while(file.hasNextLine() ){

        alphabeticPhoneNumbers.add(file.next());
        alphabeticPhoneNumbers.add(file.next());
        file.nextLine();

        System.out.println(alphabeticPhoneNumbers.get(i));
        i+=2;
    }

    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("wrong.txt");
    for( i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        pw.print(alphabeticPhoneNumbers.get(i));
        pw.print(alphabeticPhoneNumbers.get(i+1));
        pw.println();
        i++;
    }
    pw.close();

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve. If you only want to display them while the program's execution, you could use a `System.out.println` within the last `for` loop.

Comment: im supposed to display the correct numbers from the array, then all the phone numbers that are incorrect( not a number) write them to a txt file then display them.

Answer (score 0):

What is it that you're trying to achieve? I'd think that your program is broken and doesn't print anything because you're somehow incrementing `i` to a value that's already greater than 7 so your second loop doesn't do anything. Just a guess though as I don't know how your data looks like. Try not reusing index variables like `i`.

Comment: It displays the correct numbers from my txt, but the wont create and display  the new txt file

Comment: Please provide an extract of the input file. And also try and avoid reusing `i` as it'll be hard to get this right that way.

Comment: 1-800-3569377
1-800-468-5865
555-438-3663
1-800-738-6337
1-800-5299377
1-800-46-36687
713-333-6683
222-ASK-????
1800/GET-CAKE

Comment: the wrong numbers that i want the pw to write is the last two numbers

Comment: Are these numbers meant to be on separate lines? The thing is that it's really hard to see what your problem is because your code only prints every second number and doesn't do any checking for valid/invalid numbers anyway. It just doesn't make too much sense. Is all you want checking what lines are all numbers?